# Constructor must call super() or this() before return in method

Tags: java

I am getting this error:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.VerifyError: Constructor must call super() or this() before return in method JGame.Util.KeyboardMap.<init>()V at offset 0
        at JGame.Room.Room.keyboardEventTests(Room.java:81)
        at JGame.Room.Room.run(Room.java:54)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

When my application loads, it calls this method right away (KeyboardMap.map is an empty HashMap).

Here is the Method (Line 54 calls this method `this.keyboardEventTests();`):

```
protected void keyboardEventTests(){
    for(Map.Entry ap : KeyboardMap.map.entrySet()){ // Line 81
        Mapping mp = (Mapping)ap.getValue();
        if(mp.doing){
            mp.run();
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the KeyboardMap class.

```
package JGame.Util;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class KeyboardMap{

    public static Map<String, Mapping> map = new HashMap<>();

    public static void set(String key, Boolean value, Runnable run){
        Mapping mp = new Mapping();
        mp.doing = value;
        mp.run = run;
        KeyboardMap.map.put(key, mp);
    }

    public static Mapping get(String key){
        return KeyboardMap.map.get(key);
    }
}
```

Why am I getting that error, and how can I get rid of it?

Comment: Are these in different packages? Perhaps your imports are the issue.

Comment: `package JGame.Room;` and `package Game.Util;`

Comment: Have you tried a rebuild? The error looks like its complaining about a super constructor not being invoked in `KeyboardMap` however `KeyboardMap` is extending nothing...

Comment: ^^ I don't see how the code you have posted could throw that exception.

Comment: @WilliamMorrison That was it! Rebuilding the Library fixed my issue. I hate when that happens

Comment: @BrianRoach That is what I was thinking too!

Comment: If you are using Eclipse be sure to check the Project>Build Automatically. I don't use Idea but I'm sure it has similar functionality. When in doubt, rebuild, then restart your IDE, then restart your OS. If that doesn't work, come here :)

Comment: I am using Netbeans and it usually builds it, wonder why it didn't this time...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Why am I getting that error, and how can I get rid of it?

The big clue is that this is a `VerifyError`, not a compilation error.  What this means is that the JVM has found a bytecode file in which one of the constructors is not chaining properly.  These are (in effect) a malformed bytecodes.

How can that happen?

- Well it CAN'T happen in a Java class that is (just) compiled in the normal way.  The compiler will automatically insert an implicit `super()` call into any constructor that doesn't explicitly chain.
- If this is Java code, then either:

  - the class was compiled using broken compiler (unlikely!), or
  - something has tweaked the bytecodes after compilation.
- If it was some other language, then the first suspect would be the "other language to bytecode" compilation process.

I think you are getting this problem because your unit tests is using a mocking framework, and the mocking framework is using "byte code engineering" to inject something into the classes under test.  The code that is doing this has "made a mistake" and the result is bytecodes that won't compile.

---

This was apparently fixed by a rebuild, but that doesn't contradict this explanation.  A rebuild could clear out broken instrumentation code injected by the mocking framework.  And next time around, the framework could "get it right".

Answer (score 0):

Just override the default contructor by adding

```java
public KeyboardMap() {
}
```

to the KeyboardMap class. It will work.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and it was caused by a very strange thing:
In NetBeans, i use editor fold to fold long codes:

```
// <editor-fold desc="SOME DESCRIPTION">
  ...
  ...
// </editor-fold>
```

And it appeared that in one of such my folds i had forgotten to write the beginning of fold, like this:

```
  ...
  ...
// </editor-fold>
```

Correcting this **solved my problem**.
Strange, because this is just a comment and it's for NetBeans

Answer (score 0):

In my case, turning off minify in build.gradle under buildTypes helped.

```
minifyEnabled false
```