# Error exists in the bytecode

Tags: java

I have simply two class one is this every think look fine before run the program but it show errors as written below.

```
package com.ravisystem.day5;

import java.util.Scanner;


public class GetAndPrint {
// public static void main(String[]args){

Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
Student stu = new Student();
Teacher Tea = new Teacher();
//student

public void GetValueStudent() {
    System.out.println("Enter the name of student");
    stu.name = console.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter the address of student");
    stu.address = console.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter the grade of student");
    stu.grade = console.nextLine();
}

public void PrintValueStudent() {
    System.out.println("student name is " + stu.name + "\n"
            + "student address " + stu.address + "\n" + "student grade " + stu.grade);

}

//teacher
public void GetValueTeacher() {
    System.out.println("Enter the name of Teacher");
    Tea.name = console.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter the address of teacher");
    Tea.address = console.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter the salary of teacher");
    Tea.salary = console.nextLine();
}

public void PrintValueTeacher() {
    System.out.println("Teacher name is" + Tea.name + "\n"
            + "Teacher address" + Tea.address + "\n" + "Teacher salary" + Tea.salary);
}
Collage Col = new Collage();
//college

public void GetValueCollege() {
    System.out.println("Enter the name of college");
    Col.name = console.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter the location of college");
    Col.location = console.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter the establishyear of college");
    Col.establishyear = console.nextLine();
}

public void PrintValueCollege() {
    System.out.println("the name of collage " + Col.name);
    System.out.println("the location of collage " + Col.location);
    System.out.println("the establishyear of collage " + Col.establishyear);
}
}
```

**another class i have is main method class**

```
package com.ravisystem.day5;


public class ComRavisystemDay5 {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

    // scanner Console=new scanner(System.in)

    GetAndPrint gap = new GetAndPrint();
    gap.GetValueStudent();
    gap.PrintValueStudent();
    gap.GetValueTeacher();
    gap.PrintValueTeacher();
    gap.GetValueCollege();
    gap.PrintValueCollege();

}
}
```

It looks like everything's fine but show error like

```
  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.VerifyError: Constructor must call      super() or this() before return
 Exception Details:
  Location:
com/ravisystem/day5/Teacher.<init>()V @0: return
 Reason:
Error exists in the bytecode
 Bytecode:
0000000: b1                                     

at com.ravisystem.day5.GetAndPrint.<init>(GetAndPrint.java:19)
at com.ravisystem.day5.ComRavisystemDay5.main(ComRavisystemDay5.java:22)
```

Java Result: 1

Comment: possible duplicate of [Constructor must call super() or this() before return in method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18221574/constructor-must-call-super-or-this-before-return-in-method)

Comment: Which compiler/IDE did you use? If you really had this error, you either have a buggy compiler, or the compiler gave you an error message, but you decided to run the code anyway (some compilers allow that - if you do, you do so at your own risk)

Comment: In any case, the error is in the class called `Teacher` as you can see in the "Location:" of the error, and you haven't included the source code of `Teacher` (and that's the only relevant source code for this error)